# Custom binding an env variable to a configuration class property

Tags: c#, configuration, environment-variables

Following [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you may bind configuration (from `appsettings`, environment variable, or other sources) to an instance of a class. For instance, the following code will bind the `Position__PositionTitle` environment variable to the `Position.PositionTitle`.

```cs
public class PositionOptions
{
    public const string Position = "Position";

    public string PositionTitle { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<PositionOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position));
```

Motivated by the naming conventions of the environment variables where letters are all caps and separated by an `_`, I should better use the following environment variable instead:

```
POSITION__POSITION_TITLE

instead of 

Position__PositionTitle
```

This would require refactoring the property as well:

```cs
// from:
public string PositionTitle { get; set; }

// to:
public string Position_Title { get; set; }
```

where I am afraid `Position_Title` does not follow the common naming convention in c#/.NET. Therefore, I am wondering how you could define a custom mapping as the following.

```cs
[Config("position_title")]
public string PositionTitle { get; set; }
```

Comment: I need a way to configure the same thing. To bind the properties base on the key on the Environment Variable.

Comment: Why do you want to have your environment variable names all in upper case? I know that may be like a best practice or something but not limiting us to use what we want. I tried using the Env variable as "Position__Title" with value, and that exactly bound the value to the prop: Position.Title